# Rendering complex JSON/Javascript Objects in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, javascript-objects

I am trying to render an JSON object (maybe javascript object, honestly not sure) in React. The issue is that the data from my database gives each node a random name, like this "-MXD0MSwDX8FN6qUw9H0". I thought this was no big deal, but the problem is that I am trying to access the data under that node. As you can see in the picture below, I want to render the entries of "one" "two" "three" and "four" as part of a datatable.

```
[
  {
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      {
        "-MXD0MSwDX8FN6qUw9H0": {
          "four": "1",
          "one": "ABCDEF",
          "three": "1",
          "two": "ARCA"
        },
        "-MXD0MZbyi3zAodme7mL": {
          "four": "2",
          "one": "ABCDEF",
          "three": "2",
          "two": "ARCA"
        },
        "-MXD2m0143mUw6BSb5Jg": {
          "four": "1",
          "one": "ABCDEF",
          "three": "1",
          "two": "ARCA"
        },
        "-MXD2m5wE6OB8DTH6N3c": {
          "four": "2",
          "one": "ABCDEF",
          "three": "2",
          "two": "ARCA"
        }
      }
    ],
    "subHooks": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Effect",
    "value": "ƒ () {}",
    "subHooks": []
  }
]
```

So far, I have tried to convert it to an array with [].concat(tabledData), and Array.of(tabledData), but it does not seem to work, so I am currently trying to make it work with the javascript object functions. Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
{Object.keys(Data).map( (key)=>{
                return (
                    <div className="dataLine">
                            <div>{Data[key].one}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].two}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].three}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].four}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].five}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
```

I believe my error is that Data (which is my stateful value), does not have entries at Data[key].one because the child node is not one yet, its something like "-MXD0MSwDX8FN6qUw9H0". Since I cannot predict this random string, I am not sure how to acess the child of this Object without knowing the name.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you're mapping over an object's keys you *do* know the key, because you've mapped over them.

Comment: That looks good, but I guess `Data` is not what you expect. If `Data` is the whole object you posted, the nested object you’re concerned with is `Data[0].value[0]`.

Comment: You mean a JavaScript object, as [there is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: When you get data from Firebase through its JavaScript SDK, there is a `forEach` method on the `DataSnapshot`. You can use this to iterate over the child nodes in the correct order.

Comment: If that doesn't allow you to solve it, can you 1) either make the question completely separate from Firebase, and show us how the code you shared operates on the JSON you shared? 2) or show us how `Data` is read from the database, and how it relates to the JSON you shared?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your help!! much appreciated, check out my working code below. Have a good laugh at my beginnerness.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for the clarification, much appreciated!

Comment: @BenWest thanks for the comment! it was the copy paste from React Dev Tools, I should have clarified

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for your help! Helped me to get a solution! Much Appreciated!

Comment: Glad you worked it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Dave Newton for making me realize I actually did have most of it right. I am not sure what exactly I was confused about, my solution I believe should have been working as far as I know.

Big thanks to Frank Van Puffelen who got it. I used the forEach method to take the data from firebase and create a Object thingy that worked magically! I wish I understood it. If anyone has any explication that would be great. My whole code is below. My solution is super hacky, but I will refactor later when I know what I am doing more.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { database } from "../firebase"

export default function Datatable(props) {

    const [Data, setData] = useState([])


      useEffect(()=>{
        var recTradeDatabase = database.ref(props.dataName)
        recTradeDatabase.on('value', (snapshot) => {
          //const tabledData = snapshot.val()
          setData([]);
          snapshot.forEach(dataPiece =>{
            setData(currentData=>[dataPiece.val(),...currentData])
          })
          setData(currentData=>[].concat(currentData.slice(0,props.TableCutOff)))
        })
      },[props.dataName, props.TableCutOff])

    const {
        title,
        columnNames,
        ID
      } = props

     
      /* Old way of setting Data
      function setDataAsync(newData, cutLength){
        setData(arrayOfData => [].concat([newData,...arrayOfData]))
        setData(truncated => [].concat(truncated.slice(0,cutLength)))
      }
      */
    
    return (
        <div id={( ID || "")} className="datacontainer">
            <div className="title-line">
                <div>{title}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="column-titles">
            {columnNames.map(dataEntry => {
                return (
                    <div className="title">
                        <div>{dataEntry}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
            <div id="data">
            
            {Object.keys(Data).map( (key)=>{
                console.log(Data)
                return (
                    <div className="dataLine">
                            <div>{Data[key].one}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].two}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].three}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].four}</div>
                            <div>{Data[key].five}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```